# Can't read inputs on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: gpio, python

I tested everything untill now with GPIO 40 as an input, but now comes the moment where i need to connect multiple inputs.

Now i'm three inputs further, i tested input 38,37 and 36, they all seem to be low all the time, nothing changes

This is an example coding of what i use to read them in python (i'm using internal resistors):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(37, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN

if (GPIO.input(37) == 1):
    print("pushed")

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Again, it's just an example code and i'm aware that it will only read the input once when starting this program.

I need help because i'm going to have to connect 10 input buttons, and it's not looking well and i have no idea where the fault is located.

It's connected like this photo i found on the internet (gpio 7 is 40/39/38/37... in my case): http://prntscr.com/avtlol

Kind regards,
Jonas

Comment: How are you setting the GPIO high?  Could you edit your post and include a photo of your set-up?

Comment: The GPIO is connected to the pushbutton, which is connected to the 3.3V pin on the Raspberry Pi 2

Comment: This sort of error is almost invariably down to the wrong connections which is why we need to see a photo of your set-up.

Comment: i'm sure its correctly, as the gpio 40 works i actually only have to change the connection from gpio 40 tot gpio 38 to test gpio 38 in this case

Comment: Are you changing the pin number in the script to correspond to the physical pin you are testing.

Comment: yes, i change every number

Comment: does anyone know what it could be?

Answer (score 2):

Run `gpio readall` to see the state of all pins. Press buttons ard repeat.

This will let you debug your electrical connections then you can work on the program (if needed).

This is a standard debugging technique - try to test independent stages step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Just making sure you know this: BOARD numbering is not the same as GPIO or BCM numbering. you are using BOARD pin 37, which is the same as GPIO/BCM pin 26: [image: GPIO pins]
**Make sure you are connecting the input to the pin labeled GPIO26.**

Also, You say *"i tested input 38,37 and 36, they all seem to be low all the time, nothing changes"*. What is wrong with that? your using a pulldown, they should be low when your not pressing the pushbutton. It appears that the problem is in your pushbutton, not the GPIO pin. Test to make sure that the pushbutton output goes HIGH when you press it.

*Ps. is it a typo that you're missing an ending parenthesis at the end of `GPIO.setup(37, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN`?*

Comment: Please mark this as "accepted" if it works!!